# Flutter Show a page every time the user opens the app, until they click a button, then it should show a different page when they open the app

Tags: flutter, dart

The problem I’m asking is how to have a kind of page (call it SetupPage) that is only shown until the user presses a button on the screen. Then when the screen should show the next page(call it HomePage) and every time the app is opened after the button press, the normal page will be HomePage.

I’ve seen this general idea in many apps (sign-in and home page, enter phone number or school and main page, etc) and I would like to have it in my app! I’m thinking of using Navigator routes and having the stack be this at first:
(**HomePage**, *SetupPage*)
and then once the button is pressed I can pop *SetupPage*. But I’m not sure how to implement this.

I already have the SetupPage and HomePage classes made. I’m not doing a sign-in the SetupPage or anything like that. I’m not using FireBase in this app either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Flutter package [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to save a Boolean that tell you at the start of the program is the button pressed or not.

Comment: Ok thank you! But can’t I just have a normal Boolean for this?

Comment: a normal Boolean won't be saved when you open the app next time shared_preferences saves the value in the phone memory to load it when you need it again, it's also useful when you need to save the app settings or user preferences.

Comment: Ohh ok! just one more question, if I have other booleans or other values in general like arrays of strings, strings, ints, etc. that need to be saved for when I go on and off the app, do they all have to be from shared_preference?

Comment: yes, it saves them so you can retrieve them later even if the app is closed then opened again.